# How to implement onfocus() with span tag onclick() event

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have one input type field which is google inspired input type with label animation which has onfocus event and In one of the Input fields has the Password field in which I have to apply eye-toggle functionality with onclick event. I am sharing a screenshot of the input type.

[image]

When I am trying to implement toggle functionality for passwords. onclick event is not able to trigger because of the onfocus event.

Here is the code for the toggle.

CSS and icon.

```
    .form-row {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .col-3 {
         max-width: 485px;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
         flex: 0 0 485px;
    }
    
    .inputfield {
        margin-bottom: 24px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .inputfield .form-label{
        position: absolute;
        top: 23px;
        left: 20px;
        cursor: text;
        transition: top 250ms ease-in-out, left 250ms ease-in-out, font-size 250ms ease-in-out
    }
    
    .inputfield input{
        margin: 8px 0;
    }
 
    .inputfield-control {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1.5px solid #C4C4C4;
        border-radius: 5px;
        outline: none;
        background: none;
        padding-left: 16px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .inputfield-control:focus {
        border: 1.5px solid #2464E4;
    }
 
    .inputfield-control:focus ~ .form-label {
        top: 0px;
        left: 20px;
        font-size:13px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #232323;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        z-index: 10;
        padding-left: 4px;
        padding-right: 4px;
    }
    
    .inputfield-control:not(:placeholder-shown).inputfield-control:not(:focus)~.form-label {
        top: 0px;
        left: 20px;
        font-size:13px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #232323;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        z-index: 10;
        padding-left: 4px;
        padding-right: 4px;
    }

    .show-password-icn {
        font-size: 22px !important;
        margin-top: -40px;
        margin-right: 30px;
       color: #767676;
       float: right;
     }
    
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.5.6/css/ionicons.min.css"></script>
```

Because of the Animation in the input field toggle click event is not even triggered.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-password', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("icon ion-md-eye");
  var input = $("#Password");
  input.attr('type') === 'password' ? input.attr('type', 'text') : input.attr('type', 'password')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-3 inputfield">
  <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" class="inputfield-control" placeholder=" ">
  <label class="form-label">New Password</label>
  <div class="input-group-append custom">
    <span toggle="#password-field" class="icon ion-md-eye-off field-icon toggle-password show-password-icn"></span>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to perform another click event instead of the click event, but still, any of the click events are not working with Animation.

Comment: Please share full code using CSS and icon, then will let you know the quick solution for the same. Currently without knowing how you have written the css it is not answerable.

Comment: @KairavThakar Okay will update you with the full CSS code in a few minutes.

Comment: @KairavThakar, I have updated the code for CSS and icon.

Comment: Still, find CSS is not complete. Eye icon is not over the input field.

Comment: Using which css you have overlap the eye icon and the input form?

Comment: You can check , `.show-password-icn` css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update some CSS as per below:

```
.inputfield-control {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1.5px solid #C4C4C4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    padding-left: 16px;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 70px;
}

.input-group-append.custom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.show-password-icn {
    font-size: 22px !important;
    color: #767676;
}
```

Please let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: Please let me know if you find any issues,

Comment: Will try and update you ASAP.

Comment: Okay. Got it. No worries